# # en input automaticamente y css para darle color azul

Tags: javascript, html, css, formularios

Buenas amigos,tengo un formulario el cual quiero mandar por correo usando phpmailer , ya esta corriendo esa parte, la que me ha surgido es que quiero agregarle a las palabras que valla escribiendo en el input "etiquetas" un prefijo #

si escribo juan 
que el mismo se transforme en #juan y que al presionar otra tecla de letra o que no sea espacio me genere un #a

luego agregarle a eso el css para verlo de color azul para impactar
por donde puedo empezar?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea  name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo mas cercaco que pude llegar.

```js
function mayus(texto) {
  var text = texto.value.replace('#', '');
  var words = text.split(" ");
  var newTexto = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].length > 0) {
        newTexto += "#" + words[i];
      } else {
        newTexto += " ";
      }
  }
  
  texto.value = newTexto;
};
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea  name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: DIABLOS!!! esta genial , si, en efecto , es casi lo que queria hacer

Comment: me puedes explicar este codigo?

Comment: En la primera linea remueves los `#`.  Luego en la segunda separas el texto por espacios en blanco y guardas el resultado en un array `words`.  Luego en el for, iteras el array de palabras y las concatenas poniendo de prefijo `#`.